# csv "UTF8" character encoding with pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

Our client has sent us a CSV file of data that I need to import into a specific table in our Postgresql 8.3.9 database. The database uses UTF-8 character encoding, i.e. our CMS allows multiple languages such as French which are inputted  into the database via the CMS in French. One particular facility is for the client to upload images to the server and then enter "alt" tags for them in French. However, due to a bulk update required, we have been sent a CSV to feed into a particular table - for the image alt tags, in French.

The CSV has some special characters such as "é" - e.g.
"Bottes Adaptées Amora Cuir Faux-Croco Fauve Photo d'Ensemble"

The images themselves are hosted on two places - one is a CDN, and one is a local database backup and local server (web server) file backup. I am using a PHP script to read the CSV file and do the needful so that the "alt" tags are updated on two places - our web database, and the CDN.

However, when I read the CSV (using PHP), the character does not "come out" as expected.
The data is comming as "Bottes Adapt�es Amora Cuir Faux-Croco Fauve Photo d'Ensemble".

I don't think this has anything to do with the database, but it has something to do with my PHP file reading the CSV data. Even if I print the data that it is reading, the special character above does not print as above, it' prints as if the special character is not recognised. Other characters print fine.

Here is the code I'm using (not some special custom functions are used here to interact with the database but they can be ignored).  The CSV file is made up of {column 1} for image name, and {column 2} for the ALT tag.

```
$handle = fopen($conn->getIncludePath() . "cronjobs/GIB_img_alt_tags_fr.csv", "r");   
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
//normally I run a query here to check if the data exists - "SELECT imageid, image_fileref FROM table1 WHERE image_fileref = '". $data[0]. "'");
    if ($conn->Numrows($result)) { //if rows were found - 
        $row=$conn->fetchArray($result);
        //printing the data from $row here
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: You need to update this question with the exact PostgreSQL version, the exact error messages, some sample data from the CSV, the exact code you're trying to use to load the CSV into Pg, etc. As written it is too incomplete to usefully answer.

Comment: It's still impossible to answer without knowing *what exactly you're doing*. That means: post your code, please.

Comment: I've reformatted your code to be readable. Please use the preview, where you would've seen it was one giant unreadable blob. Code is indented with four spaces, or with the `{}` button in the editor. See the Markdown editing help in the editor.

Comment: I hope your other code is more careful about parameters than that code is, because it's critically vulnerable to SQL injection. What if your CSV file contained an `image_fileref` of `';DROP SCHEMA public;--` ? Read [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [the php manual on sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: I've written a basic explanation of what I guess is probably going on. To get better answers in future, you must *start* by posting the code *and* the exact text of error messages, the Pg version you're using, and a *clear description of what you've tried*. It's really hard to know from your explanation above exactly what's going on, so I've had to do a lot of guessing. I can't believe you still haven't said your Pg version or full error message text when explicitly asked; it makes me wonder if you respect the value of the time of the people you're asking to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You've still omitted key information - when asking for help with an `UPDATE` don't delete the `UPDATE` statement from the code - and your description of the problem is very confused, but there's some hint of what's going on.

### Mismatched encodings

It's highly likely that your PHP connection has a `client_encoding` set to something other than `UTF-8`. If you're sending `UTF-8` data down the connection without conversion, the connection's `client_encoding` must be `UTF-8`.

To confirm, run `SHOW client_encoding` as a SQL statement from PHP and print the result. Add `SET client_encoding = 'UTF-8'` to your code before importing the CSV and see if that helps. Assuming, of course, that the CSV file is really UTF-8 encoded. If it isn't, you need to either transcode it to UTF-8 or find out what encoding it *is* in and `SET client_encoding` to that.

Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [the PostgreSQL manual on character set support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/multibyte.html).

### Better approach

The approach you're taking is unnecessarily slow and inefficient, anyway. You should be:

- Opening a transaction
- Creating a temporary table in the database with the same structure as the CSV file.
- Use [`pg_copy_from`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php) to load the CSV into the temp table, with appropriate options to specify the CSV format.
- Merge the contents of the temporary table into the destination table with an `INSERT` then an `UPDATE`, eg:

  ```
  INSERT INTO table1 (image_fileref, ... other fields ...)
  SELECT n.image_fileref, ... other fields ...
  FROM the_temp_table n
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from table1 o WHERE o.image_fileref = n.image_fileref);

  UPDATE table1 o
  SET .... data to update ....
  FROM the_temp_table n
  WHERE o.image_fileref = n.image_fileref;
  ```
- Commit the transaction

The `INSERT` may be more efficiently written as a `left outer join` with an `IS NULL` filter to exclude matching rows. It depends on the data. Try it.

I probably could've written a faster [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)-based version, but you didn't say what version of Pg you were using, so I didn't know if your server supported CTEs.

Since you left out the `UPDATE` I can't be more specific about the `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements. If you'd provided the schema for `table1` or even just your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` I could've said more. Without sample data I haven't been able to run the statements to check them, and I didn't feel like making up some dummy data, so the above is untested. As it is, completing the code is left as a learning exercise. I will not be updating this answer with fully-written-out statements, you get to work that out.